# How come this Django plugin won't work?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, production

https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-mediasync/

The media syncs to S3, but it doesn't change the {% MEDIA_URL %} to the s3 url in my template (when I go to production)

I followed all the instructions. Here's my settings.py.

```
MEDIASYNC = {
    'AWS_KEY': AWS_ACCESSKEY,
    'AWS_SECRET': AWS_SECRETKEY,
    'AWS_BUCKET': "happy_media",
    'BACKEND': 'mediasync.backends.s3',
    'SERVE_REMOTE': True,
    'AWS_BUCKET_CNAME': True,
    'DOCTYPE': 'html4',
    'USE_SSL': False,
    'CACHE_BUSTER': 1234,
}
```

I also added this to the urls.py

```
from django.template import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('mediasync.templatetags.media')
```

I also have:

```
'django.core.context_processors.media' to my context processors in settings.py
```

Comment: Have you entered real values for AWS_KEY and AWS_SECRET?

Comment: Yes of course. Everything goes to S3. It's just that it won't turn my {{MEDIA_URL}} into the s3 url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I simply did this:

```
{% media_url %}
```

Notice that it's different from:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including  'django.core.context_processors.media' to your list of context processors in settings.py.  I think that's what exposes MEDIA_URL and makes it visible in templates.

Comment: I have that in my settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this template contex processor ?

```
django.core.context_processors.request
```